# Cannot click on a link in UIwebview with retina 4

Tags: uiwebview, hyperlink, retina-display

I would like to display a link in an UIwebviewcontroller.
I've searched and found this solution:

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",@"<html><head></head><body><a style=\"font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;\" href=\"", item.link, @"\">For more informations</a></body></html>"];
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

This solution works on all IOS but not on iphone with retina 4 inch.
Could you tell me if I did something wrong or if it's a bug of iphone simulator.

Thanks

Comment: "Could you tell me if I did something wrong" - sure, you are abusing format strings.

Comment: I understand it's not the best solution, but if I change this, do you think it will solve my problem?

Comment: I've did this with your advice:
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head></head><body><a style=\"font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;\" href=\"%@\">For more informations</a></body></html>", item.link];

Comment: @infocom That's much better. Did it solve your problem?

Comment: @mattcurtis No my problem is still here. For information the link is working with retina 3.5 inch.

Comment: There's not reason why it should not be working. This really suggests that something is wrong with your link, or other parts of your Obj-C code.

Comment: There is no such thing as a UIWebViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry it's not a problem with the link but with my scrollview with the retina 4 inch simulator, because my webview is at the end of my scrollview.